# Google protobuf and symbian

Tags: qt, symbian, protocol-buffers

I need to transfer data between c++ and java. I have decided to use Google's protobuf.

I made installation process and I got:
bin > protoc.exe
lib > libprotobuf.a
libprotobuf.la
libprotobuf-lite.a
libprotobuf-lite.la
libprotoc.a
libprotoc.la
and include folder

I've link library in .pro file

```
QT       += core gui network webkit

TARGET = MWOP
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -LC:\msys\1.0\local\lib\ -lprotobuf
INCLUDEPATH += C:\msys\1.0\local\include

SOURCES +=
...

HEADERS  += 
...

FORMS    += 
...

CONFIG += mobility

MOBILITY += bearer systeminfo

symbian {

    TARGET.UID3 = xxxxx
    TARGET.CAPABILITY += ReadUserData NetworkServices
    TARGET.EPOCSTACKSIZE = 0x14000
    TARGET.EPOCHEAPSIZE = 0x020000 0x800000

}

RESOURCES += Resources/Registration.qrc
```

in simulator everything seems to work fine and project builds but when I want to deploy application on phone I've got compilation error:
:: error: No rule to make target `\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\release\armv5\LIB\protobuf.dso`, needed by `\NokiaQtSDK\Symbian\SDK\epoc32\release\gcce\urel\MWOP.exe`. Stop.

How can I fix that?

Comment: And where is your protobuf.dso? It seems that you haven't build it. Check the path mentioned in error: is the dso file there?

Comment: I haven't got any .dso or .lib files after compilation the library and I've only got .a and .la file. Is there any way to compile this library and get .dsp .lib files?

Answer (score 1):

The DSO file you need is the ARM compiled protobuf library. I expect that the libs you list (`libprotobuf.a` etc) are windows/x86 binaries, so no use for running on target. You need to either:

- get hold of the protobuf source code and build it yourself for ARM
- find pre-compiled ARM binaries for the protobuf library

Comment: can I count on any tips how can a build the source code of that library for symbian arm? I tried to do that using msys and mingw and set configure like this: "./configure --target=arm-none-symbianelf" but I've got .a files again

Comment: I'm not sure, but I expect you'll need to build the protobuf library using the Symbian build system. For example, you could try including all the protobuf source files in your main Symbian project. I've not done anything like tghis for a long time, so I don't think I can be much more help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the [Nokia APIbridge](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/J2ME_API_Bridge_Interface), which can achieve the same thing